# How do I add the materialization runtime to a software defined asset in Dagster?

Tags: dagster

I would like to keep track of how long it takes to materialize software defined assets over time (using Dagster).

Ideally I'd add the "duration" to the materialization metadata.

I could do this very crudely

```py
import time

@asset
def my_asset():
   start_time = time.time()
   x = ...
   return Output(x, metadata:{'duration': time.time() - start_time})
```

But ideally I could avoid this boilerplate. Is this a built-in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend an `IOManager` that is implementing this behaviour in its `handle_output` method, and provide this new manager to your asset decorator via the `io_manager_key` parameter.

Comment: I would like that, but how do I access the start time of the asset materialization in the io_manager?

Comment: good point, I am guessing that the `context: OutputContext` should contain this information, but I am unsure of where to look for it..

Comment: https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/master/examples/deploy_docker/repo.py is able to get the execution time of the `op`, but I don't succeed at finding which part of the code is responsible for it.